# Using headless selenium to scrape dynamic site - Why am I not getting the script-generated content?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-chrome-headless

I have some code parsing a specific part of a dynamic webpage. Earlier I was doing it with scrapingant and it was working fine but due to the credits system it uses I decided to move to selenium. But when I try to run my code with selenium, instead of getting the dynamically generated HTML content, it just gives me the useless HTML that non-browser requests get, so it's not finding any of the elements that my code was finding before using srapingant. Any ideas? My code is below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url='https://www.mesitis.com.cy/Search.aspx?&isAsc=0&isRent=0&districts=Lefkosia&status=1&apartFloor=&types=0dfe6c47-04c5-e511-ae61-a4badb3ceace&refno=&priceFrom=170000&priceTo=260000&priceRentFrom=0&priceRentTo=10000&areaFrom=0&areaTo=1000&intAreaFrom=130&intAreaTo=500&densityFrom=0&densityTo=200&currentPage=1'

# instance of Options class allows us to configure Headless Chrome
options = Options()

# this parameter tells Chrome that it should be run without UI (Headless)
options.headless = True

# initializing webdriver for Chrome with our options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='C:\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

# getting webpage - this is where something seems to be going wrong, and I don't get the dynamically generated HTML content
driver.get(url)
page_source=driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,"html.parser")

body=soup.find('body')

properties=body.find('div', attrs={'class':'row properties-list'})

#find links of each property
allinks=properties.find_all('h3')
for d in allinks:
    print('https://www.mesitis.com.cy/'+d.a.get('href'))
```

Comment: You're using beautifulsoup to parse the page's content. Beautifulsoup is does only parse the HTML content, it does not execute any javascript or other features. Use the selenium functions like `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name` to get the right elements and their content.

Comment: @The_spider The problem is I'm not very familiar with selenium yet and I've already built a large part of the scrapper using beautifulsoup to parse. Isn't there a way for selenium to execute javascript and return the dynamically generated HTML content? Meaning the same HTML content you see when you inspect the page with a browser. Then I can continue using beautifulsoup normally as I was doing when I used scrapingant to generate the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of obtaining that data, without the overheads of Selenium: it's doable using Requests only:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

url = 'https://www.mesitis.com.cy/Search.aspx/SearchPropertiesFast'

big_df = pd.DataFrame()
headers = {
    'origin': 'https://www.mesitis.com.cy',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36',
}
payload = '{"formVars":[{"name":"__VIEWSTATE","value":"qDd5lhcP4H3kN2jINvhRjt92XZj6ix9IaKWrw9oIHKjw6zeDrrw2zWsQbGcDIZB/6U+buWRwKUTyFye1K8vyTDeTj8MbT+xSputXV4722aOhy672wwqzKKKDppNXgYLEZoM1aO0tlGNuGZrJ1EKT30FF2345a6oUPfKdrzHPyWAzxoceJ2/qFVuGQXMjAc/i"},{"name":"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR","value":"BBBC20B8"},{"name":"__EVENTVALIDATION","value":"/8kjpsksY0pg1DuYQRFVE06InIT4LHDuZT8OFTY/pxYB3czd0Ukmi9thbd9XYDPNRXLkdm+oJzu0U6g3bqVMZU5Azgj6C2V/LyMKsLq4tYuQ+KE/GKWokA74mPf53qg+8tJ75T92dXShsE32JMlhiQ=="},{"name":"isAsc","value":"0"},{"name":"isRent","value":"0"},{"name":"districts","value":"Lefkosia"},{"name":"status","value":"1"},{"name":"apartFloor","value":""},{"name":"types","value":"0dfe6c47-04c5-e511-ae61-a4badb3ceace"},{"name":"refno","value":""},{"name":"priceFrom","value":170000},{"name":"priceTo","value":260000},{"name":"priceRentFrom","value":0},{"name":"priceRentTo","value":10000},{"name":"areaFrom","value":0},{"name":"areaTo","value":1000},{"name":"intAreaFrom","value":130},{"name":"intAreaTo","value":500},{"name":"densityFrom","value":0},{"name":"densityTo","value":200},{"name":"currentPage","value":1}]}'
r = requests.post(url, data = payload, headers=headers)  
data_obj = json.loads(r.json()['d'])
df = pd.json_normalize(data_obj, record_path=['DataObject'])
df.to_csv('houses.csv')
print(df)
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
    Price   id  ReferenceNo Title   Area    Type    Sold    IsRent  PlotArea    ProjectID   ... LastUpdated propImageID IsProject   District    CoveredArea VAT IsNew   PropertyId  ApartFloor  EnergyEfficiency
0   170000.0    cf241874-a168-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    16365   2 Bedroom Old House For Sale In Kaimakli    Kaimakli    House/Villa 0   False   270 None    ... 2022-06-17T06:55:26.247 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    0   Lefkosia    0       0   ce241874-a168-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    None    20
1   190000.0    cd1a0b90-07aa-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    18001   3 Bedroom House For Sale In Anthoupoli, Nicosia Anthoupoli  House/Villa 1   False   0   None    ... 2022-10-13T10:36:39.8   09667ce7-07aa-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    141     1   288943c7-d6a9-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    None    80
2   200000.0    c42dc379-5f67-e811-bb4e-a4badb3ceace    2605    2 Storey Modern 3 Bedroom House For Sale In Da...   Dali    House/Villa 0   False   210 None    ... 2021-06-20T15:09:05.183 f37cf839-6667-e811-bb4e-a4badb3ceace    0   Lefkosia    180     0   c32dc379-5f67-e811-bb4e-a4badb3ceace    None    91
3   200000.0    6370763d-61ab-e811-b319-a4badb3ceacd    2962    Very Nice And Spacious 3 Bedroom Detached Hous...   Lakatameia  House/Villa 1   False   0   None    ... 2022-10-13T10:36:25.23  8384a75b-61ab-e811-b319-a4badb3ceacd    0   Lefkosia    170     1   6270763d-61ab-e811-b319-a4badb3ceacd    None    91
4   200000.0    7da50193-266b-e811-bb4e-a4badb3ceace    2633    3 Bedroom Under Construction Detached 4 Houses...   Tseri   House/Villa 0   False   173 None    ... 2021-06-20T15:09:38.88  c1b54437-0d81-e811-ae53-a4badb3ceacd    0   Lefkosia    150 + VAT   0   7ca50193-266b-e811-bb4e-a4badb3ceace    None    100
5   210000.0    96d0fb0a-89bd-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    18927   3 Bedroom House For Sale In Agios Dometios, Ni...   Agios Dometios  House/Villa 0   False   293 None    ... 2022-08-08T13:20:09.877 d1fadd0c-8ebd-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    140     0   95d0fb0a-89bd-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    None    38
6   211000.0    1881b78e-52d7-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    19481   4 Bedroom House For Sale In Archangelos, Nicosia    Archangelos House/Villa 0   False   296 None    ... 2022-08-10T09:32:52.27  e0c3a52d-53d7-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    130     0   1781b78e-52d7-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    None    68
7   215000.0    eaa2b630-e685-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    16834   In Excellent Location 3 Bedrooms House In Arch...   Archangelos House/Villa 0   False   180 None    ... 2022-10-10T13:53:48.94  95726746-e685-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    160     1   e9a2b630-e685-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    None    80
8   220000.0    2ad40da2-a190-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    17075   Incomplete residential development in Politiko...   Politiko    House/Villa 0   False   0   None    ... 2022-02-18T10:00:43.46  2bd40da2-a190-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    509     0   29d40da2-a190-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    None    0
9   220000.0    a19ad42e-cd59-e911-8b16-a4badb3ceacd    3846    3 Bedroom House For Sale In Spilia With Great ...   Spilia  House/Villa 0   False   0   None    ... 2022-05-25T11:57:46.77  9214ee5b-df59-e911-8b16-a4badb3ceacd    0   Lefkosia    0       0   a09ad42e-cd59-e911-8b16-a4badb3ceacd    None    68
10  225000.0    4bf71317-9cee-e911-b59c-a4badb3ceacd    5397    3 Bedroom House For Sale In Strovolos, Nicosia  Strovolos   House/Villa 0   False   280 None    ... 2022-05-16T06:40:32.417 491a8e48-a6ee-e911-b59c-a4badb3ceacd    0   Lefkosia    149     0   4af71317-9cee-e911-b59c-a4badb3ceacd    None    20
11  225000.0    082e2088-7baf-e911-935a-a4badb3ceacd    4738    4 Bedroom House For Sale In Nisou, Nicosia  Nisou   House/Villa 0   False   210 None    ... 2021-09-06T14:05:58.267 dfed3499-7baf-e911-935a-a4badb3ceacd    0   Lefkosia    225     0   072e2088-7baf-e911-935a-a4badb3ceacd    None    91
12  230000.0    8a978c4b-7383-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    16788   3 Bedroom Upper For Sale In Strovolos, Nicosia  Strovolos   House/Villa 0   False   0   None    ... 2022-02-03T14:20:16.57  a7df5018-f384-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    190     0   89978c4b-7383-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    None    68
13  230000.0    960d522b-dc39-e911-a389-a4badb3ceacd    3710    Very Nice 3 Bedroom House For Sale Very Close ...   Kakopetria  House/Villa 0   False   0   None    ... 2022-03-09T14:51:47.3   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    0   Lefkosia    0       0   950d522b-dc39-e911-a389-a4badb3ceacd    None    80
14  234000.0    1c3cbfed-2030-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    15488   5 Bedroom House For Sale In Spilia, Nicosia Spilia  House/Villa 0   False   762 None    ... 2022-05-25T11:57:23.79  dab17ebe-2130-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    180     0   1b3cbfed-2030-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    None    20
15  235000.0    b306f83b-7723-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    20722   4 Bedroom House For Sale In Lakatamia   Lakatameia  House/Villa 0   False   500 None    ... 2022-10-06T12:52:50.527 d36a70ee-8623-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    180     1   b206f83b-7723-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    None    91
16  235000.0    9925f398-c76d-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    7596    3 Bedroom House For Sale In Tseri, Nicosia  Tseri   House/Villa 0   False   0   None    ... 2021-08-03T14:02:02.54  636187c3-fe6f-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    0   Lefkosia    170     0   9825f398-c76d-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    None    91
17  235000.0    b536908d-d0a7-e911-935a-a4badb3ceacd    4605    3 Bedroom House/Villa For Sale in Dali, Nicosia Dali    House/Villa 0   False   293 None    ... 2022-10-13T11:01:48.23  4c888960-d3a7-e911-935a-a4badb3ceacd    0   Lefkosia    180     1   b436908d-d0a7-e911-935a-a4badb3ceacd    None    80
18  238000.0    e2519c9f-7188-e611-878e-a4badb3ceace    1450    3 Bedroom Detached House For Sale In Geri, Ni...    Geri    House/Villa 0   False   200 None    ... 2022-02-18T09:06:00.217 c831a074-def9-eb11-aa49-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    165     0   e1519c9f-7188-e611-878e-a4badb3ceace    None    91
19  238000.0    bfe95fce-0959-e811-bb4e-a4badb3ceace    2547    A Very Nice 3 Bedroom Beautiful House For Sale...   Kalo Chorio Oreinis House/Villa 0   False   0   None    ... 2021-06-28T08:59:28.997 48c399a4-9568-e811-bb4e-a4badb3ceace    0   Lefkosia    230     0   bee95fce-0959-e811-bb4e-a4badb3ceace    None    68
20  238350.0    fcfdc748-7990-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    8196    3 Bedroom House For Sale In Latsia, Nicosia Latsia (Lakkia) House/Villa 0   False   256 None    ... 2022-06-23T09:23:39.51  f18a96be-d5f2-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    143     0   fbfdc748-7990-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    None    80
21  239000.0    3f5369dc-8bf0-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    20038   4 Bedroom House For Sale In Dali, Nicosia   Dali    House/Villa 0   False   258 None    ... 2022-06-30T11:56:33.08  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    0   Lefkosia    190     0   3e5369dc-8bf0-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    None    80
22  240000.0    93eac30c-cd29-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    20805   3 Bedroom House For Sale In Lakatameia, Anthou...   Lakatameia  House/Villa 0   False   159 None    ... 2022-09-07T07:56:28.5   6e6adaea-692e-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    143     1   92eac30c-cd29-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    None    80
23  243500.0    753a3401-d75b-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    7339    3 Bedroom House For Sale Ιn Tseri, Nicosia  Tseri   House/Villa 0   False   700 None    ... 2022-06-09T12:06:17.957 001fea44-d75b-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    0   Lefkosia    227 + VAT   0   743a3401-d75b-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    None    91
24  245000.0    0fd2cd26-9e23-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    20733   3 Bedroom Houses For Sale In Pera Chorio, Nicosia   Pera Chorio House/Villa 0   False   581 None    ... 2022-10-06T12:42:59.047 c1ad0059-9e23-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    200     1   0ed2cd26-9e23-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    None    68
25  245000.0    bb9bd1f8-c729-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    20804   3 Bedroom Plus Office House For Sale In Tseri,...   Tseri   House/Villa 0   False   215 None    ... 2022-09-14T09:42:17.427 dac9ee2a-532f-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    178     1   ba9bd1f8-c729-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    None    91
26  245000.0    0de63389-f8ff-eb11-aa4a-246e960cbc4d    14744   3 Bedroom House For Sale In Kaimakli    Kaimakli    House/Villa 0   False   0   None    ... 2021-08-24T07:46:06.86  2d97036a-faff-eb11-aa4a-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    180     0   0ce63389-f8ff-eb11-aa4a-246e960cbc4d    None    38
27  250000.0    c6caa20d-b910-ec11-aa4a-246e960cbc4d    14865   3 Bedroom House For Sale In Mammari, Nicosia    Mammari House/Villa 0   False   586 None    ... 2022-08-02T07:51:38.443 1ebcd136-7311-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    190     0   c5caa20d-b910-ec11-aa4a-246e960cbc4d    None    80
28  250000.0    c1b1fcc5-9251-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    7090    Houses For Sale In Strovolos Nicosia    Strovolos   House/Villa 0   False   301 None    ... 2022-10-06T12:17:01.56  22c7750a-9351-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    0   Lefkosia    322     1   c0b1fcc5-9251-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    None    68
29  250000.0    b8823644-babb-eb11-aa46-246e960cbc4d    13710   4 Bedroom House For Sale In Dali, Nicosia   Dali    House/Villa 0   False   280 None    ... 2022-07-04T12:39:25.063 66596a80-bbbb-eb11-aa46-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    190     0   b7823644-babb-eb11-aa46-246e960cbc4d    None    100
30  250000.0    8cee923f-bc5c-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    16227   3 Bedroom House For Sale In Nisou   Nisou   House/Villa 0   False   456 None    ... 2021-12-21T08:42:29.78  418ba317-cf61-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    170     0   ff0e8d10-bc5c-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d    None    54
31  255000.0    ed27019b-f2db-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    8867    3 Bedroom House For Sale In Ag.Dometios, Nicosia    Agios Dometios  House/Villa 0   False   341 None    ... 2021-09-08T13:05:39.39  e756e5d2-00dc-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    0   Lefkosia    143     0   ec27019b-f2db-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd    None    80
32  258000.0    c453e74a-8bba-e811-91b1-a4badb3ceacd    3048    4 Bedroom Under Construction Detached House Fo...   Pera Chorio House/Villa 0   False   332 None    ... 2021-06-19T12:41:37.69  fa1f8fa2-8bba-e811-91b1-a4badb3ceacd    0   Lefkosia    185 + VAT   0   c353e74a-8bba-e811-91b1-a4badb3ceacd    None    100
33  260000.0    58fcb64e-443a-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    21097   In Excellent Condition 3 Bedroom Plus Attic Ho...   Anthoupoli  House/Villa 0   False   190 None    ... 2022-09-22T10:19:04.283 4e45580e-453a-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    180     1   b9497873-8039-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    None    91
34  260000.0    aef929d7-f7a3-eb11-aa45-246e960cbc4e    13205   5 Bedroom House For Sale In Lakatamia, Nicosia  Lakatameia  House/Villa 0   False   260 None    ... 2022-06-09T13:03:20.523 271593f7-f7a3-eb11-aa45-246e960cbc4e    0   Lefkosia    293     0   adf929d7-f7a3-eb11-aa45-246e960cbc4e    None    68
35  260000.0    d2106e0e-092a-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    20822   3 Bedroom House For Sale In Palouriotissa, Nic...   Palouriotissa   House/Villa 0   False   281 None    ... 2022-09-06T14:36:45.15  bfd8748a-cd2a-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    0   Lefkosia    170     1   9aff1698-0f29-ed11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d    None    80
36 rows × 21 columns
```

​
​See documentation for Requests here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And for Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Comment: Crazy how you did in a few mins what I've been trying to do for the past 5 hours. What line of text do I add if I want this written to a csv file?

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot. Out of curiosity:

Before you responded to me I also tried to get the post request from chrome and copy it into python. I first copied all from fetch/XHR as Curl into postman, then copied from postman as python code. But my code had a lot of (apparently unnecessary) extra headers that yours don't.

Did you do something similar?